# jQuery HTML transitions

Tags: jquery

I have a search results list that has say 100 items in it.  When displayed the browser scroll bar appears.  no problem so far.

However, when the user now searches again, this time netting only 8 results, the results fit on the page and the scroll bar disappears.  Again, no problem.

However what I now want to do is to make this look fancy.  So I want to fade out the results, then fade in the new ones.

The problem is that as you fade out, the whole window resizes, as it's designed to do, the scroll bar goes and then the new results are displayed.  If the new results require a scroll bar then this looks kinda odd as it first disappears then reappears.

Is there a purely jQuery way to put off the window resize, and hence keep the scroll bar visible, until the next load of results has been fully shown?

The effect I'm looking for is that if both results required a scroll bar then you fade out the first results, scroll bar stays, fade in the next, scroll bar stays.  rather than have it disappear and then reappear.

Comment: By applying CSS property `overflow-y:scroll;` you can force the container element to always display the scrollbar, whether you need it or not.

Comment: The scrollbar is on the browser not the div container.

Comment: `body { overflow-y:scroll; }` will force the `<body>` to always display a vertical scrollbar.

Comment: yes but then it's there even if not required.  i wonder if i can detect if its there, set yscroll and then hide it if not required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vertical scrollbar appears based on the height of the content in your document as compared to the window height.  So, the scrollbar appears when you add the content to the document that it taller than the window or disappears when the content is no longer taller than the window.

If you want to control the scrollbar during the transition and make it independent of the content height, then you will have to manually force the scrollbar on or off using CSS depending upon what you're trying to do.  This can be done by setting the `overflow-y` style property on the `body` object.  For example:

```
$(document.body).css("overflow-y", "scroll");
```

will force the scrollbar to stay on.  You can see the options for `overflow-y` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/overflow-y).

Comment: yeah i know, i was hoping there was a way to defer the scroll bar hide/show

Comment: @griegs - Unless you've overriden it with style settings, the scrollbar goes automatically based on the content size.  So, you have two choices for controlling the scrollbar.  1) You can control the content height or 2) You can manually specify the scrollbar.  There is no delay/defer option.

Comment: Yeah.  I was hoping there was a way tho i suspected there wasn't.  thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: It *is* possible to defer the vertical scrollbar. Shame you accepted this as the answer. =/

Comment: @Coby - why don't you provide an answer that explains how then?  The OP can always change their accepted answer if you provide a better one.

Comment: I shall work on a functional demo and get back to you, good sir.

Comment: If you can do that then i'll happily accept that answer. sorry @jfriend00 :)

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZbnNP/2/)** — How's this for an elaborate proof-of-concept?

The basic idea is it maintains the existing vertical scrollbar until the replacement comes in.

```
// Specify the height of the container, for example, height:120px;
$('.container').height($('.container').height());
// Hide currently visible content.
// Load in new content.
// Reset the height of the container i.e. height:auto;
$('.container').height('');
```

Comment: very cool.  will take a closer look a little later in the day. thanks coby